# Trying to extract text from PDF in c# in UWP

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
private void FvPDF_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = fvPDF.SelectedIndex;
    if (ResultList.Count > 0 && ResultList.Count > index)
    {
        this.DisplayText.Text = ResultList[index];
    }
}

private async void openpdf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this.openpdf.IsEnabled = false;
    FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pdf");
    StorageFile pdfFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (pdfFile != null)
    {
        // Load pdf from file.
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(pdfFile);
        uint pageCount = pdfDoc.PageCount;
        progressbar.Maximum = pageCount;
        fvPDF.Items.Clear();
        ResultList.Clear();

        for (uint i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {
            using (PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i))
            {
                InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

                // Default is actual size. Render pdf page to stream
                await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);

                // Create bitmapImage for Image source
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

                // Set stream as bitmapImage's source
                await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                // Create image as FlipView item's source
                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source = bitmap;

                // Add image item to flipview.
                fvPDF.Items.Add(img);

                // Update processbar
                progressbar.Value++;

                // New OcrEngine with default language
                OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromUserProfileLanguages();
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

                // Get recognition result
                OcrResult result = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(softwareBitmap);

                // Add to result list
                ResultList.Add(result.Text);
            }
        }

        // Show first page recognition result
        FvPDF_SelectionChanged(null, null);
    }
}
```

Well it works fine in first attempt to read the pdf file whereas when trying to read 2nd pdf, its showing error and throwing exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

in this line:

```
this.DisplayText.Text = ResultList[index];
```

How to clear the "List" so that it again work for the 2nd time and so on?

Comment: `ResultList` is of what type and how are you initializing it?

Comment: private List<string> ResultList;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            fvPDF.SelectionChanged += FvPDF_SelectionChanged;
            ResultList = new List<string>();
        }

//This is the code on top of that one

Comment: have you checked whether `index` is negative?

Comment: as mentioned in the code, index is set to selected page, so it can't be negative. The main thing here is to clear that <List> and reset all values, in order to execute 2nd time. i used ResultList.Clear(); but didn't worked.

Comment: @Naveen *"it can't be negative"* - it can, see Sunteen's answer. Please, when you ask a question here and (implicitly) are asked to check a value, don't simply dismiss that.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code snippet and it will throw the following exception as you mentioned:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Actually for this exception,  as mkl said it is caused by the value of `SelectedIndex` is "-1" that `ResultList[index]` thrown the exception. You invoked `FvPDF_SelectionChanged(null, null);` for showing the first page result and this method will get the `SelectedIndex` for using, but actually at the same time `SelectedIndex` is "-1" by default since there is no item selected. Details please reference [`SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedIndex) property.

So if you want to show the first recognize page result, you should set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 after you loaded the pdf file. Updated code as follows:

```
// Show first page recognition result
//FvPDF_SelectionChanged(null, null);
fvPDF.SelectedIndex = 0;
```